# Param in Post Request

Tags: node.js, express

I need help in my code because I can't get the param in POST request.

**Requiring route in my Entry point**

```
var messageRoutes = require("./routes/message");

app.use("/rooms/:id/messages", messageRoutes);
```

**POST Route**

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

> But if I do it like this, I can get the params.

**Entry point**

```
app.use(require("./routes/message"));
```

**POST Route**

```
router.post("/rooms/:id/messages", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

> So why is that?

Answer (score 0):

URL parameters are defined as everything after the top-level domain. If we do not give the URL a value for these it will be blank. In the case of:

```js
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

There are no parameters because there is nothing to be added to the URL to make the URL more dynamic, a purpose of adding URL parameters. This would refer to the index of the application and hence only ever be one single page. When it comes to the case of:

```js
router.post("/rooms/:id/messages", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

There are three different places here that we can change in order to make the URL more dynamic. These three different places are stored in the `req.params` object, ironically also as parameters.

Comment: As for my understanding, there is a code that telling that route is exist and has a params, correct me if Im wrong. ``app.use("/rooms/:id/messages", messageRoutes);``. ``router.post("/").....`` will be equal to ``router.post("/rooms/:id/messages")....``